# Are calls to SSL_read guaranteed to consume messages in the order they were sent?

Tags: ssl, openssl

The answer to this question could possibly be "it depends", and then my question becomes "what does it depend on?" and "what should be done so that they are received in order?".

Answer (score 2):

Yes. TLS runs over TCP which guarantees the byte order of the stream, and, as @dave_thompson_085 notes below, TLS provides record sequence numbering and will fail the transfer if it detects a sequence error.

With all that underneath you at the byte and TLS record levels, you don't have to do anything about message sequencing at the application protocol level.

Comment: TCP provides stream in spite of 'natural' errors but can be defeated by an intelligent adversary; SSL/TLS adds a MAC that includes record sequence (in pseudoheader) to prevent that (with overwhelming probability). But note a stream (either TCP _or_ SSL/TLS) provides only bytes _not_ delimited 'messages'; higher protocols/formats that need message boundaries must add them.

Comment: Note that the answer is different if you are using DTLS instead of TLS. In DTLS messages may be reordered (but you still use SSL_read()).